# How do you get multiple separate software development teams to unify their best practices?

Tags: team-management, software-development, project-team, documentation, team-building

We have several reasonably well functioning small software development teams working on different areas of the business. Each team has its own lead and roughly 8 other developers on it. The teams have no overarching boss except for the CEO, who is not involved in the day to day development activities at all.

These teams work together somewhat frequently but don't talk to each other as much as we'd like. They tend to all have slightly different cultures, and slightly different practices when it comes to various core software development activities like documentation, testing, code review etc.

These teams have a lot to learn from each other, as each has strengths and weaknesses in different areas, but I am unsure of the best way to identify what each does best and have everyone follow that.

Any tips on unifying everyone's best practices and then maintaining that state?

Comment: Are these teams working on the same product? Is there an actual need for them to coordinate and collaborate their work and have shared standards or practices? Trying to align teams on good practices for the sake of having good practices is going to look very different than teams that must work together to build and deliver a common product, and both are going to look different than independent teams building independent products within a common portfolio. More information about the relationship between these teams and what they work on would be helpful.

Comment: https://medium.com/@nezihtinas/rankabunga-measuring-a-developers-performance-1906d3e794c3

Comment: "Any tips?" makes this a polling question. While I think your underlying question is valid, I need you to edit this question to ask something that invites a canonical answer, rather than listicles of possible solutions to a generic organizational problem. Without that, the question may be edited or closed by the community to keep it within our help center guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents:

There is no need to unify the way they work if they are working well. Don’t try to fix something that is not broken!

So I would suggest something different here coming from Fractal. Make one of the engineers in each team a champion of cross-functional collaboration and facilitate meetings with them to exchange knowledge in the topics that you want to promote. That way you still let them evaluate which changes in the process are the best for their team.

Remember that there is no one size fits all.

I hope this helps to spark some ideas for your setup!

Answer (score 1):

**Hello Carthage.** While agile does encourage teams to adapt working practices I can see the advantage of having just enough consistency to make collaboration easier. It also makes it easier for people to understand what everyone else is doing and for people to move between teams.

From a finance department perspective, it might be cheaper to consolidate tooling and get better pricing. So this makes sense from an enterprise perspective.

**I would recommend two things.**

1. Start with an alignment of the reporting artefacts, I would
   recommend starting with some of the Flow reports as described in
   [SAFe](https://www.scaledagileframework.com/metrics/). Just use the ones most relevant to your organisation or the ones that the teams
   can agree on first and then build from there. As a bare minimum you
   should be using a **Cumulative Flow Diagram** to measure Load.
2. As you mentioned that the teams work together frequently, I
   would recommend doing a **PI Planning event**. That will not only allow
   an opportunity for everyone to understand what others are doing but
   will encourage planning alignment.